# Child thread won't close when main GUI window is closed in pyqt5 / pythonx3

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pyqt5

I tried this example from StackOverflow:

[How to get a child thread to close when main GUI window is closed in pyqt5 / python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61151313/how-to-get-a-child-thread-to-close-when-main-gui-window-is-closed-in-pyqt5-pyt/61151596#61151596)

I would like this child thread to terminate when I close the main application. In this example, the child thread is a simple counter. When I close the main GUI, the counter still keeps going. How can I get the thread to end when the GUI window is closed?

My code is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Apr 11 12:41:26 2020

@author: Pietro
"""

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication,QPushButton, 
                             QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
import time, threading, sys





class testScriptApp(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # initialize the widget
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        # set the window title
        self.setWindowTitle("Scripting")
        # manage the layout
        self.center()
        self.resize(400,400)
        self.mainGrid = QVBoxLayout()
        self.button = QPushButton('Start')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.mainGrid.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.mainGrid)



    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def on_click(self):
        global running
        print('global running : ' , running)
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.run()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        global running
        running = False
        print('Closing')
#       self.worker.terminate()
        event.accept()

class Worker(QThread):

    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        count=1
        global running
        while count>0 and not running:
#        while count>0:
            print('counter on: ',count, running)
            time.sleep(2)
            count+=1
        else:
            print('out of loop')
            return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    running = False
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = testScriptApp()
    myapp.show()
    app.exec_()
```

I started trying to learn Python3 weeks ago so please be gentle. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Try reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16246796/how-to-stop-a-qthread-from-the-gui

Comment: You should call `self.worker.start()` instead of `run()`. If you set `self.worker.setTerminationEnabled(True)` then in the closeEvent `self.worker.terminate()` will terminate the thread.

Comment: Yes Noah, that is working. Thank You a lot. Why do you think I cannot get the else statment of the conter to print 'out of loop'  (line 71)  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From :  [QThread : run() Vs start()](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/4486-QThread-run()-Vs-start()#:%7E:text=jpn-,Re%3A%20QThread%20%3A%20run()%20Vs%20start(),when%20it%20has%20been%20started.)

> From the docs

> QThread begins executing in run(). To create your own threads, subclass QThread and reimplement run()
> Use the start() method to begin execution. Execution ends when you return from run(), just as an application does when it leaves main()
> To create your own thread you'll always need to subclass QThread and reimplement run().
> To start the thread you'll need to call start().

> I hope it's clear now.

So like alec said

You should call

`.worker.start()` instead of `run()`.

If you set `self.worker.setTerminationEnabled(True)`

then in the `closeEvent`

`self.worker.terminate()` will terminate the thread. –

Changed code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication,QPushButton, 
                             QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
import time, threading, sys





class testScriptApp(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # initialize the widget
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        # set the window title
        self.setWindowTitle("Scripting")
        # manage the layout
        self.center()
        self.resize(400,400)
        self.mainGrid = QVBoxLayout()
        self.button = QPushButton('Start')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.mainGrid.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.mainGrid)



    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def on_click(self):
        global running
        print('global running : ' , running)
        self.worker = Worker()
        
        self.worker.setTerminationEnabled(True)
        self.worker.start()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        global running
        
        # running = False ## doesnt print 'out of loop' line
        running = True ## does print 'out of loop' line
        
        # self.worker.terminate() # if not commented out doesnt print the 'out of loop' line
        
        ### self.worker Execution ends when you return from run() 
        
        time.sleep(5)
        
        print('Closing')

        event.accept()

class Worker(QThread):

    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        count=1
        global running
        while count>0 and not running:
            print('counter on: ',count, running)
            time.sleep(2)
            count+=1
        else:
            print('out of loop')
            return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    running = False
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = testScriptApp()
    myapp.show()
    app.exec_()
```

output:

```
global running :  False
counter on:  1 False
counter on:  2 False
out of loop
Closing
```

uncommenting `self.worker.terminate()` , output:

```
global running :  False
counter on:  1 False
counter on:  2 False
counter on:  3 False
counter on:  4 False
counter on:  5 False
Closing
```

Note that I added `time.sleep(5)` in closeEvent to allow the Qthread to print the `out of loop` line.

Remember as in the link above **self.worker Execution ends when you return from run()** allowing terminate with `self.worker.setTerminationEnabled(True)` will allow to call `self.worker.terminate()` at any point.